# CSS-Bug causes repeating elements while scrolling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm facing an issue with Internet Explorer 11 (Version 11.0.9600.18204) on Windows 7. The website I'm developing seems to be having a problem displaying correctly:

[image: on Win7]

However, the same error does not appear on Internet Explorer 11 (Version 11.0.9600.18205) on Windows 8.1:

[image: on Win8.1]

Is there any way to fix this?

Edit: This is the CSS code in question:

```
div[Attributes Style] {
  text-align: -webkit-right;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
  display: block;
}
#footer {
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
```

for this piece of html code:

```
<div id="footer_container" align="right">
        <div id="footer">
            <b>
                <a href="<url>/start.ivp" style="text-decoration: none" title="Impressum">Impressum</a>
            </b><img id="j_id_t" width="10px;" height="" alt="" src="/ivy/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces"><b>|</b><img id="j_id_v" width="10px;" height="" alt="" src="/ivy/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces">          
            <b>
                <a href="<url>/start.ivp" style="text-decoration: none" title="Datenschutzerklärung">Datenschutzerklärung</a>
            </b><img id="j_id_x" width="10px;" height="" alt="" src="/ivy/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces"><b>|</b><img id="j_id_z" width="10px;" height="" alt="" src="/ivy/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces">
            <b>
                <a href="<url>/start.ivp" style="text-decoration: none" title="AGB">AGB</a>
            </b>                                                    
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding CSS-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the parent div-container and set:

```
position: static
```

This should avoid the perceived behavior.